# Lost Space in APFS Disk

Tags: hard-drive

i have a strange problem with my 250GB disk :

As you can see there is only 14GB free, whereas I use only :
First Partition -> 13GB
Second Partition -> 61GB
Total -> 74GB

So there is about 170GB lost.

With an other software I see that :

We can see the container is 255GB, and when we add every partition there is a problem =)

There is what I have with diskutil list :

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         255.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +255.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MAC                     13.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume DATA                    61.6 GB    disk1s5
```

And with diskutil apfs list :

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 650D3579-0AAC-45AA-99BE-AC11015C622C
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      255850758144 B (255.9 GB)
    Minimum Size:                 249365704704 B (249.4 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   241532342272 B (241.5 GB) (94.4% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       14318415872 B (14.3 GB) (5.6% free)
    |
    +- Volume disk1s1 4C5EF258-D10F-4CC2-830B-1D98452D92C3
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      MAC (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         13338890240 B (13.3 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 C9CB59F5-E172-4714-B54F-C5AC884A89E3
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         45064192 B (45.1 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 92A54C4A-DEAB-468E-9D05-6CB6438A9E83
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1032749056 B (1.0 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 AA7B8677-6595-4C8E-961F-A8224DE431EB
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/VM
    |   Capacity Consumed:         20480 B (20.5 KB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s5 934A085E-8D7E-403F-BD74-178727275A92
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (No specific role)
        Name:                      DATA (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /Volumes/DATA
        Capacity Consumed:         61626560512 B (61.6 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Why 94% used ???
If we add everything we get about 74GB used (disk1s1 + disk1s2 + disk1s3 + disk1s4 + disk1s5).